# win32 postmessage shift enter

Tags: python, input, pywin32, win32gui

I'm trying to send Shift+Enter key combination (new line in a textbox) to a window. I have already tested code below with no output:

```
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, int('0x1C0001',0))
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, int('0xC0000001',0))
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0)
```

I know that `SendKeys` may work but I want to use the function when the target window does'nt have focus or other events and programs are running.
Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me. Are you sure the handle is correct? Try using [WinSpy++](http://catch22.net/software/winspy-17) or the tool from [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: Thanks IronManMark20. Have you tested it on Notepad?

Comment: Actually, I just used the edit for when you're writing an answer [ :) ], so the handle was Firefox. Hmm... your code _didn't_ work for me with notepad. I will investigate more.